# How to use shortcuts while the mouse is in locked mode?

Tags: shortcut-keys, games

I was playing a game (The Dark Mod) so my mouse was locked to that window, everything was fine but I was unable to use shortcuts like Alt-F4 or Alt-Tab!
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same thing.  This is because if the last thing you clicked on was the game, any keyboard commands will be interpreted as being an instruction for the game.  If you want to use keyboard shortcuts, click on part of the screen which is not part of the game, and then use the shortcut.

Hope this helps!